# UITextView and other elements inside UIScrollView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I have my view in the following way.

[image]

I am expanding the text view programmatically depending on the text as follows

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = CGSize(width: titleAndDescriptionContainerView.frame.width, height: .infinity)
    let estimatedSize = noteDescription.sizeThatFits(size)
    noteDescription.constraints.forEach{
        (constraint) in if constraint.firstAttribute == .height{
            constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
        }
    }
    titleAndDescriptionContainerView.constraints.forEach{
        (constraint) in if constraint.firstAttribute == .height{
            constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height + noteTitle.frame.height
        }
    }
    entireScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: entireScrollView.frame.width, height: (imageScrollView.frame.height + titleAndDescriptionContainerView.frame.height + audioContainerView.frame.height))
}
```

I am also changing the size of the entire scroll view. But I am not able to scroll my view when the text is long. have a look at these screenshots.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: You can see there's a little red circle with an arrow in it, at the top right of your storyboard view hierarchy. This means there's an issue with your constraints, so you can simply tap on it and it will give you a hint about what is wrong and how to resolve the constraint conflict.

Comment: @AlexLinares that error is just about the horizontal slider width. Fixing that changed nothing.

Comment: Hmm I see. And did you make sure that your Scroll View is properly pinned to all the edges of the screen?

Comment: @AlexLinares I missed setting these constraints. Now when I did set the scroll view all sides to 0, it changes nothing. but I got these errors to scroll view has ambiguous scrollable content height and width

Comment: I think you'd be better off embedding in a stackView your ImageScrollView and your 2 container views. Check this tutorial out: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/scroll-view-layouts-with-interface-builder/

Comment: Not quite clear... I'm guessing `Audio Container View` is a view holding your Slider? Do you want that to stay visible and at the bottom? Or should it scroll with the rest of the content? Depending on what part is supposed to scroll, it looks like you have too many constraints to the scroll view's `Frame Layout Guide`. If you have your constraints set correctly, you should never need to set the `.contentSize`. Edit you question and try to clarify what you really want (as opposed to *"this isn't doing what I want"*.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are not correctly defined. You need to redefine them as follows:

1. Make sure your EntireScrollView is pinned to the edges of the root view.
2. Pin to the EntireScrollView Content Layout Guide the following:

   - ImageScrollView (top, leading, trailing)
   - Audio Container View (leading, trailing)
   - Title And Description Container view (leading, trailing, bottom)
3. ImageScrollView, Audio Container View, and Title And Description Container View need to be of equal width with the EntireScrollView Frame Layout Guide.